# Filter multiple pivot tables from a connected Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [connected Google Sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkimIhnLKGI). In a separate tab, I have a number of pivot tables deriving from the range of this connected sheet.

I want to create a way to filter all of the pivot tables based on one column from the connected sheet.

To do one at a time, I can select the pivot table, add filter, do it by value, wait for all the values to populate, select the ones I want, and then click "Apply." However, I have a number of pivot tables, and I want to be able to change them all in one action.

One way of doing that is by using a [slicer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLXazb932B8). The problem with using a slicer on a connected sheet, however, is that you can only filter by condition—they no longer allow you to filter by value (I presume because it would take too long for the value list to populate from the query).

This works fine if I want to select one value from a column. Say the column I made the splicer for is in the connected sheet and called `topic`. Where they can be A, B, C, or D. I can filter by condition if equals A, and it will return me A. But what if I want to return both A and C, but not B and D? It doesn't seem like there's a way to catch *multiple* conditions in a slicer *for a connected sheet*. It doesn't even let me choose "Custom Formula," where I could do a regex.

Filtering the tab that has the preview data of the connected sheet only changes the preview—it does not change the filtering of the pivot tables on the other tab.

How do I filter multiple pivot tables deriving from a connected sheet at once?